# Google Interview Puzzle

Tags: algorithm, probability, counting

Given n dice, each of 'a' sides and a sum b, return the number of ways in which the sum b can be obtained. How can you reduce the time complexity and space complexity?
This was asked in a Google interview and I am unsure of the answer.

Comment: Are you allowed to Google the answer?

Comment: Does "n dice, each of 'a' sides" mean that each die has values 1 through *a*? Or does it merely mean that each die has *a* values, and you have to examine a total of *n* × *a* values from a 2D array or something?

Comment: Hmm, no matter how I try to divide the problem, I can't get space complexity below O(n).

Comment: @ruakh: I think it means that you have `n` `a`-sided dice

Comment: @Jacob: Yeah, I got that part, thanks. ;-)

Comment: Yeh all n die have a sides that is numbers from 1 to a

Answer (score 7):

This is asking you to find the number of ways to write `b` as a sum of `n` positive integers. The answer is the number of [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of `b` into `n` parts, which is `(b-1 choose n-1)`.

Now if we take into account the constraint that the size of the parts is limited to `a`, the problem gets a little more interesting. I recommend using [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for this. The answer will be the coefficient of `x^b` in the product `(x+x^2+...+x^a)^n`. Why? Because for each die (the singular of dice), you have a number between `1` and `a`, and this is represented by the exponent of `x`. When you take one `x^i` from each of the `n` terms, this is equivalent to the number `i` coming up on that die. The sum of the exponents must be the sum you are after, namely `b`.

We can even simplify the problem a bit using the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) which states:

```
(x + x^2 + ... + x^a)^n = sum_{k1+k2+...+ka=n} (n multichoose k1,k2,...,ka) x^{k1+2*k2+...+a*ka}
```

where all `ki >= 0`. So the answer is that the number of ways is

```
sum_{k1+k2+...+ka=n & k1+2*k2+...+a*ka=b} (n multichoose k1,k2,...,ka)
```

Comment: "which is (b-1 choose n-1)." is wrong,,its (b+n-1 choose n-1)

Comment: @ChingPing No, the formula is correct as I've written it. The formula you give is if you take compositions into ***at most*** `n` parts.

Comment: agreed..you should have stated that :)

Comment: @ChingPing I did: "...the number of compositions of b into n parts..."

Comment: "...the number of compositions of b into n 'non zero' parts...

Comment: nice theory, but to be honest we are left with a problem that looks more harder to solve :) i.e. find k1,k2,...ka such that sum(ki)=n and sum(i*ki)=b and then do a multi choose ..

Answer (score 0):

I would have an array `hits[max + 1]` which counts the number of possible combination for each value.  `max` is `n * a` and of course `hits[0]` to `hits[n - 1]` will remain empty.

The dumb way would be to do `n` for-loop (one for each die) and register a hit in `hits` for the current sum of the dice.

The less dumb way is to use a bit of combinatorics, where I write out the number of combinations for each **ordered** shuffle:

there is  1 combination of 1111  (sum = 4)
there are 4 combination of 1112 (sum = 5)
there are 4 combination of 1113 (sum = 6)
...
there are 4 * 3 / 2 combinations of 1123 (sum = 7)
...
there are 4 * 3 * 2 combinations of 1234 (sum = 10)
...
there is 1 combination of `aaaa` (sum = `n * a`)

You need to spend much less times in the for-loops than the dumb solution.
You get many hits for each iteration instead of just one hit with the dumb method.

Those for-loops just move the (n - 1) partition separations over (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., `a`).
The separations can be on the same spot (e.g. they are all between 1 and 2 for the case 1111), but you must not have a separation below 1 or above `a`.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming a is large enough( to be specific a>=b-n), this boils down to

```
x1+x2+x3+...+xn=b
```

which is the typical problem of distributing 'b' candies amongst 'n' kids.
if you want to avoid 0 faced dies it should be easy to see that

```
(y1+1)+(y2+1)...+(yn+1)=b
y1+y2+...+yn=b-n
```

so a general solution to
    z1+z2+...zk=n is
    C(n+k-1,k-1)

**EDIT after reciving several downvotes:**

Assuming we have limit on 'a' i.e. b-n>a, 
we can formulate it as a DP problem where

```
dp[k][j] is no. of ways to get a sum of j using dices 1 to k inclusive
dp[1][j] is 0 if j>a or j==0 else 1
```

then we can have evaluate following relation

```
from k = 2 to n
  from j = 1 to b
     from x = 1 to a
        dp[k][j] += dp[k-1][j-x] where x is from 1 to a at max and x<j
```

and answer should be dp[n][b]
The storage if of order n*b and runtime O(n*b*a)

Comment: why did the interviewer ask for time and space complexity ?

Comment: This isn't right because your solution doesn't take into account that dice have a maximum value.

Comment: it should be x1+x2+....+xn = b cause there are n die and each die can maximum upto a on its face, how do you take care of that ? you conveniently ignored 'a' that is maximum each of n die can show up