# Image Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

An image(square image) can be stored as a tree: A node is white if the image is white, is black if the image is black, and is mixed if it contains both. White and black nodes are leaves, whereas a mixed node will have exactly 4 children, representing the 4 quadrants in the image. Given 2 images (trees), find the image representing their intersection. (Intersection: B^B -> B, B^W -> W, W^W->W)
This is a Google Interview Question

Comment: "This is a Google Interview Question" - but it's not a real question here.

Comment: you seem to be posting all of the questions you were asked at a google interview.

Comment: I was not asked, I did not attempt a Google Interview >.<

Comment: I refer you to another of your recent questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584803/google-interview-puzzle   where you state "This was asked in a Google interview and I am unsure of the answer."

Comment: @MitchWheat What is wrong with you, my friend gave me a list of few questions he was asked in Google interview, I figured out some and unsure of rest, hence I posted... I would have posted them from different accounts and you wouldn't have realized then.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It's an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it: Traverse both trees at the same time, using the same ordering. Build up an output tree while you do that. Then:

1. If you see a mixed node in both trees, output a mixed node
2. If you see a mixed node in one tree, but a white node in the other, output a white node (and ignore the mixed node in the traversal)
3. If you see a mixed node in one tree, but a black node in the other, copy the mixed node and it's children to the output tree
4. If you see two white nodes, output a white node
5. If you see two black nodes, output a black node

This has the possibility to create a mixed node that's actually only got white children, so you probably want a compression step where you traverse the tree collapsing mixed nodes that only have white children.

Edit: I think you could avoid the compression step by letting your recursion know whether output black nodes were found below (and putting in a white leaf if the answer was no).

Comment: "if you see a mixed node in both trees, output a mixed node" thats wrong!

Comment: @ChingPing: Why? Consider a tree with a mixed root, and four leaf children: `[WWWB]`. If you intersect it with itself, you'll get a tree with a mixed root, and four leaf children.

Comment: mixed node at non leaf level means there are black or white leaves as children , and they may still intresect

Comment: Exactly, which is why you output a mixed node :)

Comment: do you still traverse the tree there or stop?

Comment: Mixed nodes are never leaves, so you'd keep traversing. Can do pseudocode if you like, but it'll have to wait til tonight.

Answer (score -1):

Since both are represented as a binary tree you have to traverse a tree structure starting from root and check whats the color of nodes in both trees at any time and store the result in another tree. If either are black or white you stop traversing further. Else if anyone of them is mixed traverse further in that node until you find both of them of single color.

Comment: this is not necessarily binary tree, mixed nodes have 4 children

Comment: for any kind of tree this algorithm should work